# Deep linking works on device, but not in android emulator?

Tags: c#, android

We are trying to get deep linking working for android, I've added the IntentFilter to our main activity and when I build and deploy on actual device it works just fine. However, on the emulator, even though it shows the status as "always", it still fails to handle links in the emulator.

I declared the IntentFilter as following:

```
  [IntentFilter( new[] { Intent.ActionView },
              Categories = new[] { Intent.CategoryBrowsable, Intent.CategoryDefault },
              DataScheme = "http",
              DataHost = "develop.apricity-health.com",
              DataPathPrefix = "/app",
              AutoVerify = true)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
```

When I run "adb shell dumsys package domain-preferred-apps", I get the following:

```
  Package: com.apricityhealth.patient
  Domains: develop.apricity-health.com
  Status:  always : 200000000
```

However, it's in the "App verification status:" section not the "App linkages for user 0:" section, so I think this might be the problem.